how do i make it so it only types one key in pynput
i dont know how do i make it if ex. x axis is 254 and y axis is 254 it should only type one r and not spam r, i really dont know how i can fix it , someone please help
import pygame
import time
import sys
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()


# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set up the joystick
if pygame.joystick.get_count() == 0:
    print("No joystick connected!")
    sys.exit()

joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

print(f"Joystick detected: {joystick.get_name()}")


# Main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
            x_axis = int((joystick.get_axis(0) + 1) * 127.5)  # Scale to 0-255
            y_axis = int((joystick.get_axis(1) + 1) * 127.5)  # Scale to 0-255

            print(f"x: {x_axis}, y: {y_axis}")

            
            if x_axis == 0 and y_axis == 254:
                keyboard.press('2')
            if x_axis == 0 and y_axis == 0:
                keyboard.press('1')
            if x_axis == 254 and y_axis == 254:
                keyboard.press('r')
            if x_axis == 254 and y_axis == 0:
                keyboard.press('5')
            if x_axis == 126 and y_axis == 254: 
                keyboard.press('4')
            if x_axis == 126 and y_axis == 0:
                keyboard.press('3')
                    
    pygame.time.wait(100)

pygame.quit()


i tried to use time.sleep but it didnt work

Maybe you should add a flag. Like this. (It is off my mind and I have not debugged it, but you get the idea. Hopefully it works)
flag = True
if x_axis == 254 and y_axis == 254 and flag:
    keyboard.press('r')
    flag = False
else:
    flag = true

